# Datagrid is glitching and rows are getting Reordered when scrolling upwards

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia

When I run this, it gets a fairly large list of items. At first scrolling downwards has no issues at all. However when I scroll upwards it starts glitching back and forth and you can never reach the top of the DataGrid. Even more the rows start to get mixed up and no longer sit in the position they're supposed to.

```
<DataGrid 
        Grid.Row="1"
        CanUserResizeColumns="True"
        CanUserReorderColumns="False"
        CanUserSortColumns="False"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        HeadersVisibility="All"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        GridLinesVisibility="All"
        MaxColumnWidth="500"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        Background="{Binding Context.UniversalSettingsContext.BackgroundColor}"
        Items="{Binding Context.WorkItemPanelContext.WorkItems}"
        >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Allow?">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding State}" Header="State" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Description}" Header="Description" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ReleaseNotes}" Header="Release Notes" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The binding statement you have:

```
Context.WorkItemPanelContext.WorkItems
```

Is suggesting you have an odd structure behind your view. It needs flattening so you are databinding to `WorkItems`, not `Context.WorkItemPanelContext.WorkItems`.

Have a read of the Law of Demeter.

I would suggest having a read around MVVM as a design pattern and reorganise your data so it's a much more binding friendly and flatter than it is now.

It looks like you have one `god object` called `Context` that has absolutely everything on it which is not a good design choice.

There isn't anything in this code that suggest it should be behaving like this other than the deep binding I've mentioned.

Comment: Not quite, So what I have is Context is the object for the view, then its fields within the object. It's never passed around between views. This is to separate panels within the view here. The issue with my table was how it was displaying the data. The text was too long and so it overflowed, but I had it wrapping so it didnt scroll behind like normal. I just had to make certain columns larger.